# Formula based on two intervals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to develop an application and I need some simple math and can not handle it.
You can see in the image attached a simulation of the screen. What I want is in the left part (from 0...33%) to have values the values-10 -9 ... -1 0, and on the right side (from 66% - 100%) to have values from 0 .... 10.

So basically what I have is the input and the four interval limits (0, 33%, 66%, 100%) and what I want is an output in the interval of [-10, 10]

It can be also two functions, for the left hand side, and right hand side, doesn't really matter.

I know this is not that complicated, and I am a bit ashamed to ask this here, though it exceeds my knowledge in this domain and I really need help.

[image]

Comment: So you want a piecewise linear function that maps $[0,0.\bar{3}]$ onto $[-10,0]$, maps $[0.\bar{3},0.\bar{6}]$ to a constant $0$, and maps $[0.\bar{6},1]$ onto $[0,10]$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
30x-10, & 0\leq x\leq\frac13 \\
0, & \frac13< x < \frac23 \\
30x-20, & \frac23\leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}$$

assuming my comment above was correct. This is a monotone continuous piecewise linear function mapping $[0,1]$ onto $[-10,10]$.

If you need the domain to be $[0,1024]$, we can modify the function slightly to accommodate that. It isn't completely clear from the picture what you need.

**Addendum:** Let me explain how I arrived at the nontrivial parts of this formula.  Suppose you want to find the linear function $f$ that maps one interval $[a,b]$ onto another interval $[c,d]$, in that order (meaning $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$), assuming $a\neq b$.

We can do this in a few easy steps. We compose three linear maps: first, apply the map $f_1$ that shifts the initial endpoint of the interval $[a,b]$ to the origin. That's easy, use $f(x)=x-a$; this map carries $[a,b]$ onto $[0,b-a]$.

Next, apply the map $f_2$ that scales the interval $[0,b-a]$ so that its right endpoint becomes $d-c$. Again easy, just use $f_2(x)=\left(\frac{d-c}{b-a}\right)x$. Note that this is the only reason we require $a\neq b$. Note too, that the length of the image interval is the same as the length of the interval $[c,d]$, which we are about to exploit. Note lastly that it is perfectly fine if $c=d$ here, nothing is invalid in that case, the image is just a single point.

Finally, apply the map $f_3$ that shifts $[0,d-c]$ onto $[c,d]$. Again, easy. Use $f_3( x)=x+c$.

Putting these maps together, we arrive at
$$f(x) =f_3(f_2(f_1(x)))= \left(\frac{d-c}{b-a}\right)(x-a) +c
$$

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't that clear. It seems that I have trouble expressing myself :).
Your first assumption was right (I need a linear function that maps [0, 33%-of a value] to [-10,0] and [66%-of a value, that value] to [0, 10]); the domain will not necessarily be [0, 1024], it will depend on the users' screen resolution.

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I wanted. Your explanations are very clear and I can finally understand what happens here. Thanks! :)

Comment: You're quite welcome. Now you can do this sort of thing from first principles if you ever need to do it again. It's a nice tool to have in your toolbox.

Comment: I highly appreciate that you also explained how you came to the results, that helps a lot!